# how do I do "model" calculation in Plone or Zope

Tags: plone, dexterity, z3c.form, zope3

This is a really basic design question, but I can't seem to find an answer.  I'll use a really simple example, but my concern is for cases where the model-level calculations, "2+2" in this example, become complex.

Let's say I'm designing an application to run in Zope or Plone; its job is to add two numbers.  Dexterity lets me easily create a content type with fields addend1 and addend2, and will generate add, edit, display forms for me.  I could modify the display form to also present a field named "sum," but "sum" is a result of extensive calculation in my model, and I don't want to present it in the "add" or "edit" forms because I don't need that as input, just as a result of calculation.  I don't want to calculate it in my view, because it's expensive, I'd like to reuse it after initially calculating it, and I don't want my "view" to need any knowledge of how I do my calculations anyway.

So what is the proper "zca"ish approach for doing model-work that has nothing whatsoever to do with presentation of results?  Do I create an interface like ISum and create an adapter that converts my content type to one including a sum, then do a view for the ISum interface?  If not that, what?  Searching PP4D and the Zope 3 Developers Handbook hasn't helped.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use events; you can register event handlers for when your content type is added, or edited, and you set the value on the object whenever these events trigger your handler.

Comment: Thanks.  That's an approach I've experimented with; it feels like an odd way to do things, though.  I'd welcome more opinions about whether this is considered the standard way to do what I'm talking about.  If it is, I can get past my feelings.

Comment: OK, I see Martijn is a god, or at least a demi-god, so I'll go with the add and edit events unless I see counterarguments here.  Thanks again.

Comment: + 1 for Martijn's answer, no counterargument, confirming your estimation about Martijn's god-state ;)